# Scriptable way to add notification to Action Center?

Tags: windows-10

[Mac has a way to post, from command line, a notification](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-center-notification-from-an-applescript-or-shel).

Is there a Windows 10 equivalent to putting a simple notification into the Action Center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this something you could use? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730952.aspx

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon 

$objNotifyIcon.Icon = "C:\Scripts\Forms\Folder.ico"
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = "Error" 
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "A file needed to complete the operation could not be found." 
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "File Not Found"

$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $True 
$objNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000)
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize it was just a NotifyIcon. I've used those before back in Win7. I think I'll put together a barebones C# app to clean up my scripts a little.

Comment: Unfortunately, ShowBalloonTip's notification disappears after specified amount of time (and that is limited to 30 seconds I think) from the screen and Action Center. Is there a way to make it stay, apart from calling ShowBalloonTip again every 30 seconds (which will probably annoy user if it closes the notification explicitly)?

Comment: @LOST did you find an answer? My balloon tip sometimes stays in Action center and sometimes disappears after timeout

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov I have not

Comment: @LOST All I found is [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/02/adaptive-and-interactive-toast-notifications-for-windows-10/), but it's not a lightweight and scriptable way tho

Answer (score 7):

First, use the following function with -Message to generate a slide out toast notification for PowerShell.

```
function New-ToastMessage
{
<#
        .SYNOPSIS
        Displays a toast notification with a message and optional image.
        .DESCRIPTION
        Displays a toast notification with a message and optional image.
        .PARAMETER message
        The text message you want to display in your toast.
        .PARAMETER ActionCentre
        Send this to the action centre.
        .PARAMETER image
        An image that you wish to display alongside the message.
        .EXAMPLE
        New-ToastMessage -message "Alert: Disk Space Low (5%)" -image 'C:\Users\Robin\Documents\disk-low.png'
        .EXAMPLE
         New-ToastMessage -message "Alert: Disk Space Low (5%)" -image "C:\Users\Robin\Documents\disk-low.png" -ActionCenter
        .NOTES
        Author: Robin Malik
#>

param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,HelpMessage = 'Toast Message?')]
    [String]
    $Message,

    [Parameter(HelpMessage = 'Send to action centre')]
    [Switch]
    $ActionCentre,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,HelpMessage = 'Path to image?')]
    [String]
    $Image
)

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

$notificationTitle = [DateTime]::Now.ToShortTimeString() + ': ' + $Message

[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] > $null

if($Image)
{
    $templateType = 'ToastImageAndText01'
}
else
{
    $templateType = 'ToastText01'
}

$template = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::GetTemplateContent([Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastTemplateType]::$templateType)

#Convert to .NET type for XML manipuration
$toastXml = [xml]$template.GetXml()

if($Image)
{
    $toastXml.GetElementsByTagName('image').SetAttribute('src',$Image) > $null
    $toastXml.GetElementsByTagName('image').SetAttribute('alt','overlay text') > $null
}
$toastXml.GetElementsByTagName('text').AppendChild($toastXml.CreateTextNode($notificationTitle)) > $null

#Convert back to WinRT type
$xml = New-Object -TypeName Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument
$xml.LoadXml($toastXml.OuterXml)

$toast = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification]::new($xml)
$toast.Tag = 'PowerShell'
$toast.Group = 'PowerShell'
$toast.ExpirationTime = [DateTimeOffset]::Now.AddMinutes(5)
if($actioncentre)
{
    $toast.SuppressPopup = $true
}
$notifier = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier('PowerShell')
$notifier.Show($toast)
}
```

You will then be able to see PowerShell under the Windows 10 Settings > System > Notifications & actions > Get Notifications from these senders.

Click PowerShell and enable 'Show notifications in Action Centre', like so:

[image: PowerShell notifications area for Windows 10]

Finally, you can call the above function with the -ActionCentre switch to send it there instead.

Comment: where are these powershell settings, please?

Comment: @JordanMorris I could only see PowerShell in the list after I'd fired off a notification once. Spent about 10 minutes hunting for it wondering if a new build of W10 had removed it, but no. Run the function once with just -Message, then you can modify PowerShell to allow it to send to the action centre. If you can verify this I'd appreciate you marking it as the answer!

Comment: @JordanMorris I have restructured the answer so it's easier to follow. I changed the spelling to 'centre' in the code to match my build/locale, but the screenshot is old and still shows 'center' so ignore that.