# How to send notifications to the Action Center?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I have only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31751857/scriptable-way-to-add-notification-to-action-center), which seems not to be related to the Action Center.

I guess there is a simple way to send a notification with PowerShell, but I seem incapable to find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The notifications that show up in the action center tend to be Toast Notifications that the user didn't click away while they were on screen.

e.g. I insert a blank dvd, get a toast asking what I want to do with it but don't click it, it then shows up in the list of notifications in the Action Center.

I'm not sure of a way to bypass the toast step.

So what you probably want to have are Toasts (maybe silent?) which will wind up in the action center.

I wrote a powershell module for displaying these Toasts, [BurntToast](http://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/BurntToast/) (or check out the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Windos/BurntToast) for instructions and examples, etc.)

Feel free to use the module as is, or rip it apart to figure out how it works and do your own implementation. There are plenty of examples and [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868266.aspx) of how to do this in C# and/or modern applications too, now that you know the keyword to search for.

Comment: More upvotes !  Question, is it possible to get a list of the current toast notifications?  I have a scenario where I want to send a notification when it doesn't already exist (want to avoid sending too many)

Comment: Thanks for your work on BurntToast @Windos. I was able to get similar code working in my own Toast notification function. The key to this was two fold; 1) Under 'Notifications and Action Settings' in Windows 10, navigate to 'Get notifications from these senders' and click 'PowerShell'. Enable 'Show notifications in action center'. 2) Where $toast is defined as `[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification]::new($xml)` set `$toast.SuppressPopup = $true` - this forces the notification to the Action Centre. Perhaps a switch parameter could be added to your New-BurntToastNotification function?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Robin. I've been meaning to get stuck in and update this module so I'll add that to the list

Answer (score 0):

How about some toast with your job?

```
Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier JobEnd -EA 0| Unregister-Event
$action = {
if ($sender.State -eq 'Completed') {
    Write-Host $sender.Name -fore green
    Import-Module d:\scripts\BurntToast
    $global:jobInfo = Receive-Job $job
    New-BurntToastNotification -Text 'Job Completed'. "Job:  $($sender.Name) was successful"
}
}
$job = Start-Job { Start-Sleep -Seconds 5; 1 .. 5 }
Register-ObjectEvent $job -EventName StateChanged -SourceIdentifier JobEnd  -Action $action
$job.State
```