# Pop-up in PowerShell and display in notification area in Windows 10

Tags: powershell, popup

I want to display a pop-up on user's desktop (should come on top of all windows) + notification in the Win 10 notification area. I want to achieve this using PowerShell.

Comment: Hi, you could check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31914939/how-to-send-notifications-to-the-action-center

Answer (score 1):

Hy,

This is to display a pop-up

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("Operation Completed",0,"Done",0x1)
```

And for Windows 10 Notification, maybe you can try this : https://gist.github.com/altrive/72594b8427b2fff16431

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to stick with a pure PS pop-up, this is what I came up with.
Works calling from within other functions, and from buttons. This is just a testing script for me, and everything in the main code is global, so I don't need to pre-create the variable and pass it in.

This function works perfectly well without the ($msg) parameter and the ($msgText) input. So feel free to omit the parameter brackets entirely.

```
function msgPopUp($msg){
#Create Default Document Form
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $msgForm = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
    $msgForm.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(400,200)
    $msgForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $msgForm.Text = "New User Setup Information"

#Write Message on msgForm Box
    $msgLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $msgLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(0,0)
    $msgLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,200)
    $msgLabel.Text = $msg
    $msgForm.Controls.Add($msgLabel)

#Display msgForm   
    $msgForm.ShowDialog()
}

$msgText = "Fun times for all " + $msgForm.Text
msgPopUp($msgText);
```