# Windows 10 notifications in python

Tags: python, windows-10, toast

I've tried a lot of methods found online to create notification bubbles through python, but none of them work. I suspect this has something to do with windows just not allowing them for the script, but how can I solve this?

For example, using [the balloontip snippet](https://gist.github.com/BoppreH/4000505), and in my own script:

```
import balloontip
```

Following with either of these just doesn't show any toast.

```
w=balloontip.WindowsBalloonTip('asdf', 'qwerty')
balloontip.balloon_tip('asdf', 'qwerty')
```

I've also tried using the win10toast package but still no such luck.

What's even weirder is that solutions entirely unrelated to python also don't work. For example [this powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31809988/5914936) creates an icon in my tray but the message won't show.

Comment: First, please specify you GUI framework, since, it does not clear. Does it base on wxWidgets, Qt. Or maybe it's kivy or even you have a plain web-js project.

Comment: I don't use a GUI framework - the script is supposed to be ran silently in the background (pythonw) by a native C++ WINAPI app with the exception of showing one notification to indicate success.

Answer (score 4):

Try to import all the modules used in the snippet, and include the snippet in your script. You might need to install win32api using `pip install pypiwin32`
This might help you identify the problem/check if it is indeed a problem with Windows notifications in general.

I was able to create a notification by adding the following code to the end:

```
balloon_tip("test title", "test message")
```

Check if you have blocked windows notifications: 
http://www.howto-connect.com/disable-enable-app-notifications-on-windows-10/

Comment: I have pywin32 installed. What's interesting is that balloontip does indeed create a system tray icon called 'tooltip' (when hovered), but the notification itself wont pop up.