# PowerShell - How to view existing BalloonTip notifications

Tags: powershell

Every question I find on this is how to *Create* balloontip notifications. I know how to create them, but now I want a way to check if there is a notification that was initiated by another application.

I'm not super experienced with .Net classes and whatnot, so bare with me. According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon?view=netcore-3.1), the "System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon" class is specifically for creating a new notification icon--so how would I be able to access the existing ones? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this has what you are looking for - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31751857/scriptable-way-to-add-notification-to-action-center

Comment: If you want to open Action Center to view previous notifications that have not been cleared, `Start-Process -FilePath 'ms-actioncenter:'`